# Redirect to static page if EE database is down

Tags: database, error-pages

We have a client that would like to see a branded, non-EE error message if there is a problem with the EE database connection. Their database is hosted on a different server and has, on one or two occasions, lost the connection – causing EE to render a plain error message.

We'd either like to redirect to a static HTML page which contains a nice, branded apology for the site being down, or to edit the source code of the default message. I tried the Custom Messages add-on but it seems that this requires EE and the DB to be functioning correctly in order to work.

Any thoughts on how best to approach this scenario?

Gaz

Comment: Would love to see the final answer written out clearly and selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148033/how-do-i-check-if-php-is-connected-to-a-database-already

I suspect you will have to insert something like this in the site root index.php for it to work, you could then include a static template from somewhere else on the server when a connection can't be made and serve a 404 header?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Yeah, I guess that would work:
`if (mysql_connect(...)) {
  require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT;
}
else {
  redirect...
}`

Comment: I would avoid doing a redirect personally as a user might click 'Refresh' after seeing the message and in this scenario they wouldn't get routed back to the page they requested. :)

Comment: Good point. Thoughts on serving a 503?

`if (mysql_connect(...)) {
   header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
   header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
   header('Retry-After: 3600');
   include 'static_template.php';
 }
 else {
   require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT;
 }`

Comment: Oops, wrong way around...but you get the idea ;-)

Comment: Just tried a quick test. Works nicely.

Comment: Nice - glad you got it working, would make a nice little blog post write up - also, EE should do this by default. :)

Comment: Hi Gary - would be great if you could mark this question an answered by my suggestion or add your own answer with a code snippet. ;)